# LinkdeList hackerrank challenge - Print all Nodes

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I am stuck on this supposedly very simple data structure question. The link to the problem is here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/print-the-elements-of-a-linked-list/problem?isFullScreen=true

Can someone point out how to approach this correctly?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    
    private class Node{
        int data;
        Node next;
        private Node (int data){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
        }
    }
    
    static void setHead(LinkedList<Integer> lList){
        Node head;
        if (lList.peek() != null){
            head = lList.peek();
            return;
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }
    
    static void input(LinkedList<Integer> lList){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = scanner.nextInt();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < count){
            int data = scanner.nextInt();
            lList.add(data);
            i++;
            }
        scanner.close();
        return;
    }
    static void printLinkedList(LinkedList<Integer> lList){
        while(lList.head != null){
            Sdtout.println(lList.head.data);
            this.head = head.next;
        }
        return;
    }
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        LinkedList<Integer> n1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        setHead(n1);
        input(n1);
        printLinkedList(n1);
    }
}
```

**Errors:** (I am very confused how to set the head node giving a linkedlist)

```
Solution.java:19: error: incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to Solution.Node
            head = lList.peek();
                             ^
Solution.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
        while(lList.head != null){
                   ^
  symbol:   variable head
  location: variable lList of type LinkedList<Integer>
Solution.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
            Sdtout.println(lList.head.data);
                                ^
  symbol:   variable head
  location: variable lList of type LinkedList<Integer>
Solution.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
            Sdtout.println(lList.head.data);
            ^
  symbol:   variable Sdtout
  location: class Solution
Solution.java:41: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
            this.head = head.next;
            ^
Solution.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
            this.head = head.next;
                ^
  symbol: variable head
Solution.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
            this.head = head.next;
                        ^
  symbol:   variable head
  location: class Solution
7 errors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the `LinkedList` class built-in in the JDK. Instead, you have to utilize a very basic custom implementation of the [*Singly linked list*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list) data structure.

If you choose the language level **Java 8**, then almost ready to go implementation will be provided for you.

You only need to implement a *single method* that does precisely what required according to the challenge description, and nothing more:

```
public static void printLinkedList(SinglyLinkedListNode head) {
    SinglyLinkedListNode cur = head;
    while (cur != null) { // while current node exists
        System.out.println(cur.data); // print its data
        cur = cur.next;               // and reassign the current node to its next node
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million, I was using Java 15 but I guess the java 8 solution works as well

Comment: @username_1326 You're welcome. Also note, that there's no need for explicit `return` statement when method is `void`.